# preventDefault stops window.location.href from working

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete, preventdefault

My site has two ads on it, one of them uses a script which parses all links on the site and does `preventDefault()` on them... this makes it impossible for me to use preventDefault() on any links since it can only be done once... However in the past I've been able to work around this using `return false`. For some reason it doesn't work with the jQuery ui autocomplete function though (see code below).

If I turn off the ads the script works fine. Otherwise it just reloads the page because the `return false;` doesn't seem to work...

Script I **cannot** change:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // stuff
    });
)};
```

**My script:**

```
$search.autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response){
    $url = "suggestions/";
    $.get($url, {data:request.term}, function(data){     
        response($.map(data, function(item) {
        return {                
            label: item.movie_name,
            id: item.movie_id
        }
        }))
    }, "json");
  },
  minLength: 2,
  dataType: "json",
  cache: true,
  focus: function(event, ui) {
    return false;
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    window.location.href = ('/id/'+ ui.item.id +'/'+ ui.item.label +'/');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the behaviour with this code, and what is your intended behaviour? `return false` has the same effect as `e.preventDefualt(); e.cancelBubble()`, does that explain what you're seeing?

Comment: See my edits, my intention is to redirect to the perm link.. but return false; wont fire..

Comment: I don't understand, `return false` shouldn't block the redirect. Do you mean your select callback isn't called? Does `autocomplete` work on `a` elements?

Comment: The jquery-ui-autocomplete function creates a list of links (<a>)-tags, normally you would use ``preventDefault()`` to stop the browser from going through to the href address, since in my case that is not possible I tried using ``return false`` instead but since that doesn't work either in this case I finally figured, why not change the link-tags href to the correct url instead and not halt the action, which works!

Comment: the list of link-tags are the suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works:

```
  select: function(event, ui) {
     $('.ui-autocomplete a').attr('href', '/id/'+ ui.item.id +'/'+ ui.item.label +'/');     
  }
```

**Explaination:**
The jquery-ui-autocomplete function creates a list of links ()-tags, normally you would use `preventDefault()` to stop the browser from going through to the href address, since in my case that is not possible I tried using `return false` instead but since that doesn't work either in this case I finally figured, why not change the link-tags href to the correct url instead and not halt the action, which works!